# Что такое функциональное программирование?

Tags: терминология, функциональное-программирование

Часто противопоставляют функциональный подход и ООП. Не совсем понятно, почему? Что отличает функционально программирование? Лямбды и наличие функций типа map, fold, reduce и т.д.?

Update:
В чем заключается функциональный подход с точки зрения практики?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Функциональное программирование - способ организации вычислений без состояния. Строго говоря, состояние у такой программы конечно есть, это - совокупность контекстов всех её функций. Но: *главная проблема, стоящая за сложностями состояния, идентичности и изменения, состоит в том, что, введя присваивание, мы вынуждены внести в свои вычислительные модели понятие времени (time). До того, как появилось присваивание, наши программы от времени не зависели — в том смысле, что всякое выражение, обладающее значением, всегда имело одно и то же значение.*

На практике, используя ФП вы идёте от простого к сложному: организуете зависимости, отношения, преобразования и композиции функций. Способы делать это - суть методологии ФП. Функции ваши восновном "чисты", не мутируют внешнего контекста, а их результат зависит только от переданных параметров. ФП полностью избавляет от возможности совершения целого класса ошибок (cм.  *[SICP Х. Абельсон, Д. Д. Сассман](http://newstar.rinet.ru/~goga/sicp/sicp.pdf): гл. "Ловушки императивного программирования*").

Неверно считать, что в функциональном стиле можно писать только на языке сверхвысокого уровня с искусственным интеллектом вместо компилятора. Разумеется, это можно делать на любом языке программирования, в котором есть [функции высшего порядка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0). Более того, механика функций - основа любого интерпретатора и эта механика довольно проста, а вот введение самого понятия переменных и их мутации сильно усложняет устройство интерпретатора.

ФП противопоставляют ООП восновном потому, что в обратную сторону пошла волна хайпа, созданная в своё время вокруг Java и C++. Оказалось, что библиотеки шаблонов и многоуровневые иерархии объектов не решили всех проблем, даже наоборот, создав новые. По-прежнему бесконтрольно возрастает сложность программных систем, а соответственно и их стоимость. Тут мы наблюдаем рациональное обращение отрасли к фундаментальным основам, имеющее целью уменьшить энтропию.

Comment: +1. Сдвинем рейтинг с 666 вверх ;-)

Comment: да, типичный способ отладки императивного сайта :)

Comment: @11111000000 это у вас в нике год рождения закодирован? )

Comment: Вы всегда идете от простого к сложному - это называется декомпозиция. В любой методологии.

Comment: @hardsky: Всё так, но противоречия не вижу. Суть ФП, по-идее, раскрыта в следующем предложении

Answer (score 11):

В императивном подходе (а ООП может быть им, и обычно им и является), программист расписывает, как именно нужно исполнять его программу.

В функциональном подходе программист пишет "что нужно сделать", а вот как это делать, решает компилятор или транслятор.

Всякие лямбды, map/reduce ещё не делают программирование функциональным.

Тут на самом деле комплексный подход. К примеру, в императивном стиле принято делать изменяемые переменные (да, тавтология), а в функциональном стиле принято использовать неизменяемые переменные и чистые функции (чистые функции это такие функции, результат которых зависит только от входных параметров и не зависит от ничего другого. Также они никак не изменяют окружение. А так как их результат не зависит от внешних параметров, то их результат можно закешировать или беспроблемно вычислять в параллель).

В императивном подходе нужно детально расписать каждый шаг и в правильной последовательности. В функциональном просто - вычисли все это, вот тебе функция. И рантайм сам сообразит, как именно это вычислить, возможно переставив некоторые расчеты местами. Также в функциональном подходе активно используется "ленивый подход", когда некоторые функции могут не вычисляться до тех пор, пока они реально не понадобятся. И если, к примеру, рантайм видит, что нужно вычислить выражение `сложная_функция(1,2)/сложная_функция(1,2)`, то он просто пишет 1 и даже не вычисляет - потому что нет смысла. В императивном подходе компилятор теоретически может сделать такую оптимизацию, но для этого ему нужно проанализировать функцию и убедиться, что она не имеет побочных эффектов и тому подобное.

Comment: Ну программист в любом случае описывает для машины "что нужно сделать".

Comment: Настойчиво рекомендую найти любую книгу по хаскелю или лиспу (scheme - новый популярный диалект) и немного попрактиковаться.

Comment: Ответ хороший, спасибо. Т.е. функциональное программирование - это активное использование функций как параметров и результатов в д.р. функциях и неизменяемые переменные, правильно? P.S. а "что нужно сделать" и "вычисли все это, вот тебе функция" - это уже магия, а не программирование, лучше отредактировать ответ.

Comment: Вот как раз эта магия и делает функциональный подход таким. Поэтому ее не нужно выбрасывать. Если о ней не знать, сложно писать нормально на функциональных языках.

> Т.е. функциональное программирование - это активное использование функций как параметров и результатов в д.р. функциях и неизменяемые переменные, правильно?

конечно же, нет:) Скажем так, почти нет чистого функционального подхода (ну разве лиспа, ML и ещё некоторых) и чистого императивного (даже ассемблер уже не тот - процессор может переставлять инструкции, а на си можно передавать функции)

Comment: Ну, мне тоже близка идея не обезличивать свою работу, но ваш ответ запутывает :)

Comment: Неизменяемая переменная называется не переменной, а константой =)

Comment: Расскажите программистам на лиспе/хаскеле, что они программируют на константах:). Но в других языках не хуже. К примеру, final в java - хотя их и называют константами, но это "однократно изменяемая переменная в определенных условиях".

Comment: @KoVadim, вопрос скорее в практическом применении. В общем-то на любом языке я могу вычисления убрать в функцию и вызывать ее в коде. В чем заключается функциональный подход с точки зрения практики?

Comment: убрать код в функцию и вызвать - это не проблема. Но это не делает код функциональным. Если хочется делать код "более функциональным", используйте чистые функции, map|reduce (их имя сильно зависит от используемого Вами языка).

но если хотите точно понять - попробуйте пописать на чистых функциональных языках. А то наш разговор похож на то, как зрячий объясняет слепому, какого цвета слон.

Comment: Да, главное не путать чистые функциональные языки с функциональным подходом. Основой оного является вовсе не магия оптимизации лямбда-выражений, а именно вычисление без состояний - эту модель можно реализовать практически на любом языке программирования, особенно если в нём реализованы функции высшего порядка, т.е. функции позволяющие принимать функции в качестве аргументов и возвращать их в качестве значений.  Так называемое "чистое" функциональное программирование - лишь одна из методологий реализации лямбда-исчесления.

Comment: @KoVadim: Вы уверены что Scheme "новый популярный диалект"?

Answer (score 2):

В противопоставлении ООП и функционального, проблему сужают до противопоставления того кем манипулирует, либо функциями, либо изменяемыми объектами. Но это слишком узкий взгляд: объектами могут быть функции и функции могут хранить значения. Императивное программирование стало популярно из-за относительно простой трансляции таких программ на популярные процессорные архитектуры, на которых программы, в функциональном стиле, особо выдающихся результатов не демонстрируют, т.е. более сложная и более продолжительная трансляция функциональных программ дает код несколько худшего качества на них. Но программы на изменяемых состояниях(объектах) невозможно смасштабировать, если заранее не внести дополнительные механизмы распределения нагрузки ( по ядрам, компьютерам, сетям ), разделения ресурсов ( файлов, общих зон памяти ) и взаимной коммуникации для получения результатов работы. Вопрос в другом — может ли функциональное программирование упростить решения этого вороха проблем?! И да, и нет. Высокоуровневое функциональное SQL представление *помогает* распределять нагрузку на реляционные базы, но об линейном росте от количества ядер(компьютеров) речь не идет. Высокий уровень OpenGL позволяет писать программы выполняющие гигантские объемы вычислений, даже в императивных языках(так он был создан), распределяя нагрузку на GPU ядрах. Но нехватка ресурсов была и остается узким местом любой программы, для любой операционной системы. А коммуникации — к решению этих проблем только подходят, и императивные языки пытаются решать их в функциональном стиле, полностью отказавшись от управления в «ручном» стиле «состояний».

Comment: Текст интересный, но из него не понятно что такое функциональный подход.

Comment: SQL не функциональный язык. Да, по сути своей он декларативный, но не функциональный. Он ближе к логическим языкам (т.е. всевозможным Прологам).

Comment: А как может быть декларативный язык быть не функциональным, Даже таблица задает некоторую функцию. А Прологи, SQL, DBase... в основном, функциональные языки, с императивными трюками, иногда.

Answer (score 1):

### Книга Грокаем функциональное мышление

Стр. 28

**функциональное программирование** (ФП), *сущ*.

1. Парадигма программирования, для которой характерно использование *математических функций* и предотвращение *побочных эффектов*.
2. Стиль программирования, использующий только *чистые функции* без *побочных эффектов*.

Разберем термины.

К *побочным эффектам* относится все что делает функция помимо возвращения значения: например, отправка электронной почты или изменение глобального состояния. Побочные эффекты могут создавать проблемы, потому что они происходят при каждом вызове вашей функции. Если вас интересует только возвращаемое значение, а не побочные эффекты, значит, в программе происходит что-то непреднамеренное. Функциональные программисты обычно стараются избегать побочных эффектов, которые не являются абсолютно необходимыми.

*Чистые функции* — функции, которые зависят только от своих аргументов и не имеют побочных эффектов. С одними и теми же аргументами они всегда выдают одно возвращаемое значение. Можно называть их *математическими функциями*, чтобы отличить от функций как элемента в программировании. Функциональные программисты уделяют особое внимание использованию чистых функций, потому что они более просты для понимания и управления.
Определение подразумевает, что функциональные программисты полностью избегают побочных эффектов и используют только чистые функции. Тем не менее это не так.

Функциональные программисты, работающие над реальными программами, используют побочные эффекты и функции с побочными эффектами.